# What's are the advantages of L2TP/IPSEC over plain IPSEC?

Tags: network, ipsec, vpn

As the title says, my firewall (Sonicwall) can do either IPSEC or L2TP/IPSEC for VPN connections. One advantage of L2TP/IPSEC I can see is that the client computer get allocated its own IP address on the LAN.

Are there any other advantages?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[L2TP/IPSEC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3193) wraps a simulated data link layer in IPSEC. Plain IPSEC just encrypts the network layer.  If you want hosts to think they're on the same LAN, use L2TP/IPSEC; if you'd rather skip the extra bandwidth and processing overhead, use IPSEC.

Comment: What about tunnel and/or transport mode with IPsec. And hey ESP also. I really don't understand why L2TP is required?